# What SO site to use for font related questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Is there a SO family + SE site where I can ask questions related to fonts and also font recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://ux.stackexchange.com/ - but search first and look for any existing questions.

In fact there's already a question that might fit the bill - [What fonts are good and which ones should we avoid for our application's UI?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-fonts-are-good-and-which-ones-should-we-avoid-for-our-applications-ui)

However, font recommendations can be subjective so be careful how you word your question (if you do decide to post) and try to make it as objective as possible.

Comment: What about a "Which free font do you think goes best with a Happy Birthday card?" kind question?

Comment: @Lazer - probably not the sort of expert question we want, but you could ask and see what happens.